# When does Qheaderview get its model?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qheaderview

You can access the underlying model of a Headerview with self.model(), but when you use this in the constructor it returns None.

For example, this will print 'None'

```
class MyHeaderView(QHeaderView):

    def __init__(self, orientation, parent):
        super().__init__(orientation, parent)
        print(self.model())
```

The Headerview is set in the constructor of a QTableView subclass, which at that time already has its model set.

```
self.setHorizontalHeader(MyHeaderView(Qt.Horizontal, self))
```

So it should be able to know what its model is during construction, but it doesn't seem to. When the GUI is running, the model of the headerview can be accessed without problems.

Why does this happen? and When does the model become available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent argument alone is not enough to set the model (since the parent could be any kind of widget, not only an item view), but it's important to add it in order to properly "initialize" it with the widget's style, palette, font, etc.

The model is actually set only when the header is set on the view (`setHeader()` for tree views, `setHorizontalHeader()` and `setVerticalHeader()` for tables), but **only if** no other model is already set on the header.

The model is again set when `setModel()` is called on the view, and in this case *any* previous model is replaced with the new one for the headers.

If you want to do something with the model (for instance, connect to a custom function when rows or columns are added/removed/moved), you should override `setModel()` of the view:

```py
class MyHeaderView(QHeaderView):
    def setModel(self, newModel):
        currentModel = self.model()
        if currentModel == newModel:
            return
        elif currentModel:
            currentModel.rowsInserted.disconnect(self.myFunction)
            currentModel.rowsRemoved.disconnect(self.myFunction)
            currentModel.rowsMoved.disconnect(self.myFunction)

        super().setModel(newModel)

        if newModel:
            newModel.rowsInserted.connect(self.myFunction)
            newModel.rowsRemoved.connect(self.myFunction)
            newModel.rowsMoved.connect(self.myFunction)

    def myFunction(self):
        # do something
```

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question, and with some strategic prints I was able to confirm everything you said about when the models are set. I can solve my issue by passing the model as an argument to the constructor, and use setmodel() there. I do not really understand what your code example does, but that doesn't matter. I don't have to switch models during runtime.

Comment: @mahkitah the code overrides the default `setModel()` of the header, and *that's* where it should be properly set and where the base implementation should be called. What it does is to show what could and *should* be done when the model is set (or replaced). Be aware that if you're going to set the header on a view, `setModel()` will be called *anyway* and *again* once you call `setHeader*()`, so, again, the *proper* place to do all your stuff is in the override of `setModel()`.

Comment: "and that's where it should be" - I don't think I have anything to put there. I don't need to make connections to signals from the model. I just have a method that needs to get data from self.model().headerData() during construction (and later also). And as you said in your answer, setHeader() does not override the model that's set in __init__ (and even if it did, it would be the same model anyway, in my case)

Comment: The connections are just an example of what could be done. The point remains: if you need to do something with the model, it *should* be done in `setModel()`. You could obviously do whetever you want, but at your own risk: setting the model in the init of the header *has* side effects, **exactly** because the model has already been set and it's the same when calling `setHeader*`. For instance, the selection model is **not** updated, if `highlightSections` is `True` (defaults to false, but it's true for the default headers), the sections won't be highlighted when the selection is changed.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're losing me. Take the little code example from my question. How would you make that 'print' the model by overriding `setModel()`? I would think that whatever you put in `setModel()`, there would still be no model to print at that point. Am I wrong there?

Comment: Okay, I Think I get it now. You would put the print below the super() call in setModel(). Am I right there?

Comment: @mahkitah exactly. There are rare cases for which the header should need the model in its constructor, and it's conceptually wrong anyway (unless you *really* know what you're doing), since at that time the model could not be set yet (Qt expects that). If you *do* know that the model is already set on the parent view at that point, the parent *is* the view, and you need some kind of initialization there, there's no need to call `setModel()` in the init, as you can already access it using `parent.model()`. Otherwise, you can do anything *after* `super().setModel(newModel)` as shown in my code.